# jQuery on submit preventDefault() does not works

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, onsubmit

I have html form with submit button and input='file' control:

```
<form action="/Profile/UploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="OnUploadSubmit(this)">
```

OnUploadSubmit function looks like this:

```
  if (e.files[0].size > 5000000) {
        $('#upload_error').css('display', 'block');
        $('#upload_error').text('The file size is too large for upload')
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    var files = e.files;
    var ext = $('#file_uploader').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    if ($.inArray(ext, ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png']) == -1) {
        $('#upload_error').css('display', 'block');
        $('#upload_error').text('Only, jpg, jpeg, png is allowed');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

e.preventDefault() and return false; doesnot working form is submiting anyway.

Does anybody knows what is my problem?

Thanks

Comment: `e` should be an event object, that you can get as a first argument of your handler.

Comment: I think you need onsubmit="return OnUploadSubmit(this)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

first you can't use preventDefault  in this way because you not passed event object into function, and next:

```
onsubmit="return OnUploadSubmit(this)"
```

i Recommended:

add id attribute and remove onsubmit:

```
<form id="upload" action="/Profile/UploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){ // Document Ready

        $('#upload').submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
         if (e.files[0].size > 5000000) {
                $('#upload_error').css('display', 'block');
                $('#upload_error').text('The file size is too large for upload')
            }

            var files = e.files;
            var ext = $('#file_uploader').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            if ($.inArray(ext, ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png']) == -1) {
                $('#upload_error').css('display', 'block');
                $('#upload_error').text('Only, jpg, jpeg, png is allowed');
            }
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Does your method definition for OnUploadSubmit contain e as a parameter? If it does not, e.preventDefault will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `onsubmit="return OnUploadSubmit(this);"` instead of `onsubmit="OnUploadSubmit(this)"`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `onsubmit="return OnUploadSubmit(this)"`