# Calculate form inputs onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a dynamic form that is being generated based on what the user adds to the cart.

For example, the form will looks something like this,

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" name="cart" id="cart">
    <input type="text" name="sku1">
    <input type="text" name="sku2">
    <input type="text" name="sku3">
    <input type="text" name="sku4">
    <input type="text" name="sku5">

    <div class="sum" id="sum"> Total: {SUM SHOULD SHOW UP HERE)</div>
    <button name="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But those input fields are generated automatically and may be more or less than 5 fields.

How to calculate those input SUM value and output to SUM div without page refresh?

JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: `var t; $("input[name^=sku]").each(function(){t+=parseFloat($(this).val())}); $("#sum").html("Total: "+t)` is one way using jQuery - you can use this on a form submit, or input keyup event

Comment: @SmokeyPHP This is actualy a valid answer, you shouldn't use the comments to answer the question.

Comment: @Skwal Yea, I just couldn't be bothered to use more verbose selectors/variable names and didn't want to post a lazy answer. No point posting now though, Tushar's got it covered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('button[name="submit"]').click(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('#cart input[name^="sku"]').each(function () {
        var val = isNaN(+this.value) ? 0 : +this.value; 
        sum += val;
    });
    $('#sum').text(sum);
});
```

---

Or

```
var inp = $('#cart input[name^="sku"]');
inp.change(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    inp.each(function () {
        var val = isNaN(+this.value) ? 0 : +this.value; 
        sum += val;
    });
    $('#sum').text(sum);
});
```

[Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

[isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Comment: I don't think he wants that on submit

Comment: This will result in a concatted string of the values

Comment: Thanks for the code, it results in this, [code]Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #12345 input[name^="sku][/code], I have to add that the form id may also be numeric such as <form id="12345">.

Comment: @D_Guy13 oh i missed to close `"` see updated answer .

Comment: mmm, still nothing happens. Console doesn't output anything either.

Comment: My bad, my code needed a small modification. Thank you very much.

Comment: @D_Guy13 Glad u reached your goal  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onsubmit` attribute of the form to do whatever you want to before the form gets submitted. You can change `action` attribute also. You can also `preventDefault` as said here-

[jQuery on submit preventDefault() does not works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551345/jquery-on-submit-preventdefault-does-not-works)

Answer (score 0):

You can give the elements a class, `amountForTotal`, and use a function to calc the total, which you can add to a button, or onchange event of an input.

```
function calcTotal( $elements ){
    var total = 0;
    $elements.each(function(){
        // if the input has no value, add 0, if it has, add the value
        total+= this.value.length===0 ? 0 : parseInt(this.value); 
    })
    return total; // return the total
}

$elements = $('.amountForTotal'); // select them
// Bind an event to recalc the total
$elements.on('keyup', function(){
    alert( calcTotal($elements) );
});
```

In this code I provided the `selector` as input. This is luxery, not needed, you can add that selector in the function, but this way it can be used more flexible. You can use the `[name^=*]` selector here, but its slower than a class, which you might notice in large documents.

Also, In my code I check if it has to no value to prevent errors. You can expand this to test if the input is actualy a number.